# Exclamation point problem when renaming files with cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, utf-8, filenames

I am using the following batch to randomly name files in a folder. Initially, i had a problem non English letters. I solved this problem with `chcp 65001` . But i have problem with exclamation point. If a file name has exclamation point, the batch cannot change file name.

```
chcp 65001

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET PrependOnly=0

SET Undo=0


SET TranslationFile=Translation.txt

IF NOT {%Undo%}=={1} (

    ECHO You are about to randomly rename every file in the following folder:
    ECHO %~dp0
    ECHO.
    ECHO A file named %TranslationFile% will be created which allows you to undo this.
    ECHO Warning: If %TranslationFile% is lost/deleted, this action cannot be undone.
    ECHO Type "OK" to continue.
    SET /P Confirm=
    IF /I NOT {!Confirm!}=={OK} (
        ECHO.
        ECHO Aborting.
        GOTO :EOF
    )

    ECHO Original Name/Random Name > %TranslationFile%
    ECHO ------------------------- >> %TranslationFile%

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('DIR /A:-D /B') DO (
        IF NOT %%A==%~nx0 (
            IF NOT %%A==%TranslationFile% (
                SET Use=%%~xA
                IF {%PrependOnly%}=={1} SET Use=_%%A
                
                SET NewName=!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!-!RANDOM!!Use!.sat
                ECHO %%A/!NewName!>> %TranslationFile%
                
                RENAME "%%A" "!NewName!"
            )
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO Undo mode.
    IF NOT EXIST %TranslationFile% (
        ECHO Missing translation file: %TranslationFile%
        PAUSE
        GOTO :EOF
    )
    FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%A IN (%TranslationFile%) DO RENAME "%%B" "%%A"
    DEL /F /Q %TranslationFile%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I only show the way for `undo=0`.

```
chcp 65001

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Undo mode.
IF NOT EXIST %TranslationFile% (
    ECHO Missing translation file: %TranslationFile%
    GOTO :EOF
)
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%A IN (%TranslationFile%) DO RENAME "%%B"
```

The problem is in the `FOR` loop, you read the content of a file.
But using `%%A` or `%%B` while delayed expansion is enabled will destroy exclamation marks.

The solution is to disable delayed expansion, at least temporarily.

```
setlocal DisabledDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%A IN (%TranslationFile%) DO RENAME "%%B"
endlocal
```